# DEM to RGB-GeoTIFF (land-/waterarea colored separate)

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, rgb

I want to create a colored basemap out of a ETOPO dataset.

Is there a way to color the land (masked by a landpolygon) and water area separate and combine them later. The result should be one GeoTIFF (RGB) with land and water areas in different color gradients. 
To use one color gradient with the break at 0 meters isn't enough.

The software doesn't really matter. I prefer QGIS, but ArcMap is also ok.
I know how to do that with GMT (Generic Mapping Tools).

Is there maybe a possibility to create GeoTIFFs out of the PS-Files with same resolution as the origin ETOPO dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combined the colored GeoTIFFs with:

```
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata "0 0 0" -addalpha ouput.vrt water_rgb.tif land_rgb.tif
```

after that, I exported the vrt as 3 band GeoTIFF